# FixedThreadPool not executing properly

Tags: java, threadpoolexecutor

I have created the newFixedThreadPool of size 100 and starts 500 threads on it.
All the threads are started properly and all take enough time which they all should take. But then executor just shut down with some thread produced output and most of them not. 
I have called the shutdown() and awaitTermination() with max value also so that it must wait till all the threads are finished.
This works fine when the tasks are small in number like 20 or 30 with same pool size as 100.
The logic in thread is to operate over list and convert that list to xlsx file.
Please share any information if anyone had face similar issue.

Answer (score 1):

A common mistake with submitting tasks to an ExecutorService is ignoring any errors which occur.  You have to either;

- call Future.get() on each Future returned by `.submit(task)` to see any error or
- you have to catch and log all error in a `try { } catch (Throwable t)` block.

Most likely an error occurs which is casing all the tasks to fail.

BTW If you have a CPU bound tasks, the optimal number of thread might be the number of CPUs you have.

> The logic in thread is to operate over list and convert

A much simpler approach is likely to be to use parallelStream e.g.

```
listToProcess.parallelStream()
             .map(l -> process(l))
             .forEach(row -> save(row));
```

Comment: Yes I did the future.get() , still faced the same issue , I also logged all the exception in individual threads (there was none in actual). I will try with thareds = number of CPUs but not sure am I doing CPU bound tasks or not.